# Android - Soft touch pad hides ListView items

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, touchpad

I have a `ListView` wich contains `EditText` views. When touching these `EditText` views, the soft key pad comes up (as desired).

When using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` the touch pad hides the bottom part of the `ListView` and thus possibly the `EditText` view in focus (just touched). I know that this can be solved by using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">`. However, in this case due to resizing the `EditText` view loses focus.

I am now wondering whether it would be possible to both have the key pad not hide the `EditText` view and also have it not lose focus.

Comment: I would be able to re-focus the TextView programmatically if there was an event telling me that re-sizing was finished. I do not know of such an event though.

Comment: Actually, it seems I would not be able to re-focus programatically.